# What does "Exception thrown at 0x00007FF651C0A1CA in CK2game.exe: 0xC0000005:" mean?

Tags: visual-studio

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF651C0A1CA in CK2game.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000148F5AFFDE0.

Or how do I interpret this? Specifically, what do 0x00007FF651C0A1CA, 0xC0000005, and 0x00000148F5AFFDE0 mean?

Comment: If you know a little about assembly language and Win32 API, then you can easily interpret such native errors. But in general you shouldn't waste your time on such if you are not the author of the program. Find its vendor and ask them to fix the issue.

Comment: It would appear that `CK2game.exe` is a game called Crusader Kings II.  Is it safe to assume this is an application for which you neither contributed to nor have access to the source code?  If so, that makes this [a computer support question](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and not [a programming question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

although I can't tell what it means I can tell some things by the format, in this case, 0x00007FF651C0A1CA means the place where the error occurs in ck2game.exe and 0xC0000005 is the error. hope that helps a little bit, I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

The program start address and function table locations are variable, however, the error is runtime and most likely means that an instruction at 0x00007FF651C0A1CA attempted to access a memory address that had been deallocated or is not within the accessible memory range for that process.